# NASM - org changes addresses or only specifies load address

Tags: assembly, nasm, memory-address

I was trying to understand NASM's `org` directive, and reading about it from various online sources has left me confused.

Here are my questions:

- Does `org` *only* specify the address in memory where the program will be loaded ?
- Does `org 0x10` imply that the first instruction following the `org` would be considered at address 0 and 0x10 be added to it ? If yes, would it affect the addresses of labels used in instructions assembled between these two points ?
- If I use `org` in one program, and load another program where I don't use `org`, will the value of the first program be continued to be used here, or some other mechanism is followed ?

Please excuse me if some of these questions seem very dumb, this has got me very badly confused.

Comment: The `org` directive is available only in `-f bin` output format (and some exotic ones). It advises Nasm at what address the program is expected to be loaded - it does not cause it to be loaded there. If no `org` directive is given, Nasm defaults to `org 0`. In effect, the value given is added to the file offset of all labels/variables in the file. http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11/html/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

The `ORG` directive simply adds the given value to any relative internal addresses within your code. Labels are an example of this, as are variables located in your various code sections.